# UDP - Optional Checksum

Tags: tcp, error-handling, udp, packet, checksum

From what I have read about UDP, it has no error handling, no checking for things like sequence of data sent/recieved, no checking for duplicate packets, no checking for corrupt packets and obviously no guarantee that the packets sent are even received...

So with that in mind, why an earth is there actually an option to use checksums in UDP?? Because surely if you want to make sure the data being sent is received in the correct order (and not corrupt and so on) then you would use TCP...

Comment: "no checking for corrupt packets" - clearly, your reading was incorrect, since there *is* a checksum for that purpose. There's no mechanism to resend corrupt packets, but you can at least detect them and throw them out.

Comment: @Blorgbeard Ah right ok. So in UDP the optional checksum is just for checking if a packet which has been received is corrupt or not. Right. Thanks you very much

Comment: Yep. Also I just noticed it's not optional in IPv6.

Comment: @Blorgbeard Interesting - Still every year seems to be the year that IPv6 takes over haha..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

UDP packets include a field for a 16 bit CRC checksum which the receiving operating system will use to check for packet corruption.  If the checksum is present and fails, then the packet will be silently discarded.  It is up to the application to notice that the packet disappeared and take corrective action.

UDP checksums are enabled by default on all modern operating systems.  It is possible to disable UDP checksums in IPv4, either at the socket or OS level.  Doing so would reduce the CPU overhead of processing each packet at both the sender and receiver.  This might be desirable if, for example, the application were calculating its own checksum separately.  Without any checksum, there would be no guarantee that the bytes received are the same as the bytes sent.

Comment: Wow great answer. However in IPv6 checksums are mandatory, so the application would have no choice but to process them in that case?

Comment: The application does not process the UDP checksum, and normally would not even be able to see it.  That is handled at the network layer and may occur in the OS kernel, network driver, or network interface card.  If the checksum fails, the receiving application will never see that packet: it just disappears.

Comment: Is there a way to disable UDP checksums for IPv6 ? (reason being https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6935)

Comment: I am not aware of any way to disable IPv6 UDP checksums.  Note that while RFC 6935 proposes an exception to the mandatory checksum rule, that does not mean any particular network stack will implement it.  I did some searches and was not able to find an ioctl calls or the like, so I suspect (but am not sure) that RFC 6935 has not been widely implemented.  I am curious to hear if you find out otherwise.

Comment: @Seth could you explain little bit what you mean here "socket or OS level"?

Comment: Depending on the operating system and hardware, changing checksum handling may require sockopt(), sysctl(), modifying the kernel, or changing the NIC driver settings.

Answer (score 3):

The task of UDP is to transport datagrams, which are "network data packets". For UDP, every data packet is a transmission of its own. If you send 3 packets, those are three independent transmissions for UDP. Whether the content of these 3 packets somehow belongs together or if these are three individual requests (think of DNS requests, where every request is sent as an own UDP packet), UDP doesn't know and doesn't care. All that UDP guarantees is that a packet is either transmitted as a whole or not at all; either the entire packet arrives or the entire packet is lost, you will never see "half of a packet" arriving. So if you just want to send a bunch of data packets, you use UDP.

The task of TCP, on the other hand, is to transport a stream of data. It's not about packets. It's about a stream of bytes somehow making it from one host to another. How this happens, e.g. how TCP is breaking the data stream into chunks and sending these chunks over the network and ensuring that no data is lost and all data is in order, is up to TCP. All that TCP guarantees is that the bytes will arrive correctly and in order at the other side, unless the TCP connection is lost, in which case the stream ends abruptly somewhere in the middle but all data, that arrived up to that point, did arrive correctly and in correct order. So despite TCP also working with packets, the transmission behaves like a stream that has no internal "data units". When sending 80 bytes over TCP, there may be one packet with 80 bytes or 10 packets with each 8 bytes or anything in between, you cannot know and you don't have to.

But just because you use UDP doesn't mean you don't care for data corruption in UDP packets. Keep in mind that corruption may not just affect your data, it may also affect the UDP header itself. If only a single bit swaps, the UDP packets may have an incorrect destination port. So they added a checksum which ensures that neither the UDP header nor the data payload has been corrupted but made it optional, so it's up to you whether you want to use it or not. If used, corrupt packets are dropped and thus behave like lost packets. If your code takes care of lost packets, it will automatically take care of corrupt packets, too.

With IPv6 though, the checksum was dropped from the IP header, which means that IP header corruptions are no longer detected. But this was seen as a small problem, as most layer 2 protocols have their own mechanism to detect corrupt data (e.g. Ethernet and WiFi already guarantee that data is not corrupted on its way through the network) and the checksums of UDP/TCP also cover some of the IP header fields, so even without layer 2 error checking, the recipient would notice if the IP addresses in the header have been corrupted along the way and drop the packet. As a consequence, the UDP checksum is no longer optional with IPv6.